# Reload count objects when login

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

When the user login, I need that `books_to_discard`field (in Purchased), get the count objects that `rating < or = 1` (in Rating).

I try it,

views.py

```
def discard(request):
   discard_today = Rating.objects.filter(user=request.user, rating__lte=1)
   a = discard_today.count()
   purchased.update(books_to_discard=a)
   for object in purchased:
      object.save()
```

but it get the same value to all `books_to_discard` field : sum of all objects like `rating=1`. It didn't separate for each collection.

So, how can I return this update that can I get all of count objects of each own collection like `rating=1`and post on each own `books_to_discard` field, 
separated into their own object with the correct collections.?

rating/models.py

```
class Rating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
    rating = models.IntergerField(default=0)
```

book/models.py

```
class Books(models.Model):      
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    book = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
```

collection/models.py

```
class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

purchased_collections/models.py

```
class Purchased(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) 
    books_to_discard = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: You want to get all user ratings where the rating is less than or equal to zero? Then increment `Purchased.books_to_discard` by that number?

Comment: No, I want to get all number of objects (books) that rating is less than or equal to 1, and post this result in the ```books_to_discard``` field.

Comment: What does the `Purchased` model represent?

Comment: @Iain Shelvigton, Purchased represents purchased books. I need three things: A) Get the counting objects with ```Rating.rating < or = 1```. B) Separate this count according to each ```collection```. C) Put these counts in `` `Purchased.books_to_discard````.